# Perform a division every set amount as a variable grows - python

Tags: python

If I have the following sequence which is being iterated over from a for loop (and this sequence can be different every time),

```
freq = 10

for var in table:

    sequence = (size * var) + sequence
    size = max(size, round(sequence/freq))
    # Output = 20000 30000 40000 35000 50000 60000 70000 49000 80000
```

When the sequence hits 40,000 freq becomes 5
When the sequence hits 60,000 freq becomes 2.5
When the sequence hits 80,000 freq becomes 1.25

The issue is I cant simply half the freq when the sequence is greater than 20000 as it will half constantly, I can write hundreds of if;s for each condition but I feel like there must be a more efficient solution.

Comment: 0-40k freq is 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep trace of the last time you halve your freq

```
freq = 10
next_seq = 40000

for var in table:

    sequence += (size * var)
    size = max(size, round(sequence/freq))
    while sequence >= next_seq:
        next_seq += 20000
        freq /= 2
```

In this case, freq will be equal to 10 until sequence equal 40000, then 5 until sequence equal 60000, etc...

EDIT: I've changed `if` to `while`, in case your sequence would increase by more than 20000 in one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it for every `var` (this may or may not be needed):

This carries an additional potential benefit of allowing for sequences which do not strictly rise.

```
freq = 10

for var in table:

    sequence = (size * var) + sequence
    if sequence < 20000:
        divisor = freq
    else:
        divisor = freq / (2.0 ** (sequence//20000 - 1))
    size = max(size, round(sequence/divisor))
    # Output = 20000 30000 40000 35000 50000 60000 70000 49000 80000
```

this makes it increment every 20k starting at 40k:

```
>>> freq = 10
... for num in [0, 19999, 20000, 39999, 40000, 59999, 60000, 79999, 80000]:
...     print (freq / (2.0 ** (num//20000) - 1) if num >= 20000 else freq)
10    # 0
10    # 19999
10    # 20000
10    # 39999
5.0   # 40000
5.0   # 59999
2.5   # 60000
2.5   # 79999
1.25  # 80000
```

**NOTE**: This is relying on integer division for the halving. The `//` division is necessary in Py3 to achieve this result. On Py2.7 it's equivalent to `/`.